# Searching for an old planet shooter game

Tags: identify-this-game, windows-98

I remember playing a game when I was younger, it involved two players each having their own planet with a canon and the canon had different kind of missile attacks. These missile would damage part of the planet or any nearby planet. Gravity also affected the missile path.

I can't seem to find the game , I dont even remember the name. It was great fun playing co-op on the same PC.

I think I played it on windows 98 (or maybe XP).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sounds like a [*Scorched Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_Earth_(video_game)) derivative, in which case you should provide more detail -- there have been a *lot* of games like that over the years.

Comment: Do you remember whether it was Windows-based or DOS-based? Rule of thumb: if it opened multiple windows, it's Windows-based. If it ran full-screen and you couldn't access the start bar or desktop, DOS-based. If the window title was Command Prompt or MS-DOS Prompt, DOS-based. If the window started black with a white `_` that may or may not have been flashing, DOS-based. If you could open or save files from a file picker with icons, Windows-based. And so on.

Comment: It ran full screen , but I started it from an exe

Comment: @Mark thanks I provided all the information I could remember, I wasn't Scorched Eath, it was more graphical

Comment: Also similar is ASTER from the [HP 83/85 Games II Pac](http://www.hpmuseum.net/images/85_GamesII_AsterScreen-32.JPG)  Spent many an hour playing that back in the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Warheads](http://www.mobygames.com/game/warheads)?

Warheads an old gravity-based planetary shooter, in the same vein as Scorched Earth.  And according to Moby Games (linked above) it was created in 1997, so that would be right around the time of Win 98.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I think this is the one I was looking for , let's see if I get any more answers

Answer (score 4):

I did a bit a research based on @arron's answer and found there's a second version to Warheads game called [Warheads SE](http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/warheads-se)

This was the game I was looking for! :)